# Creating a global interceptor for all defined routes

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I have multiple route builders within my project,

I want to define a single **interceptSendToEndpoint** that will affect all of the defined routes
For Example:

```
Public Route1 extends RouteBuilder {
  
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("direct:endpoint1").toD("http:\\someAddress1");
  }
}
```

```
Public Route2 extends RouteBuilder {
  
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("direct:endpoint2").toD("http:\\someAddress2");
  }
}
```

what I want to do here is to define a central **interceptSendToEndpoint** that will automatically capture all traffic sent to the camel HTTP component for all routes.

```
public class InterceptRoute extends RouteBuilder {

  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    interceptSendToEndpoint("http:*")
        .process(exchange -> System.out.println("Hi from intercept"));
  }
}
```

However due to how camel injects the intercept scope, I'm unable to do this easily,
Is there a way to tell the camel context that this intercept is for all defined routes within the context?

Note: I'm using camel 3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Camel team works for similar task in there (https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/CAMEL/issues/CAMEL-16757?filter=allissues&orderby=cf%5B12310200%5D+ASC%2C+priority+DESC%2C+updated+DESC).

Create an abstract base class and define your in there and then extends it in main route

```
public abstract class BaseRoute extends RouteBuilder {

  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {
    interceptSendToEndpoint("http:*")
        .process(exchange -> System.out.println("Hi from intercept"));
  }
}


 public class TaskRoute2 extends BaseRoute {
    
      @Override
      public void configure() throws Exception {
        super.configure();
        from("direct:endpoint2").toD("http:\\someAddress2");
      }
    }

public class TaskRoute2 extends BaseRoute {
    
      @Override
      public void configure() throws Exception {
        super.configure();
        from("direct:endpoint2").toD("http:\\someAddress2");
      }
    }
```

Comment: While Yes this will work, I was looking to a way that doesn't include changing the parent of my routes

For now as I collect my routes (RouteBuilders) via the spring context, I simply introduced a loop to add the 
Interceptor to all routes that are collected by my context before adding them to the camel context

I'm checking if there is a smarter way to do this

Regarding the link you provided, Yes I'm aware that this is solved in modern versions of camel
But I'm unable to currently upgrade the project version.

Comment: what is your camel version

Comment: My camel version is 3.0.0

Comment: hmm . maybe you can upgrade and use it camel.apache.org/manual/route-configuration.html